# add <ion-tab> to specific view

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm new to ionic. I have a component called `firstPage`, this has a normal html view.

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar >
    <ion-title align="center">first.</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
  <button ion-button
          block
          color="primary"
          [navPush]="second">
    Ir página 2 navPush.
  </button>
</ion-content>

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {  NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { secondPage} from '../index.paginas';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-first',
  templateUrl: 'first.html',
})
export class firstPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
  }
  second:any=secondPage;
}
```

and I have another component called `secondPage`.

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title align-title="center">second</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content padding>
  esta es la segunda XDDD
  <button ion-button block color="primary" navPop>back</button>
  <!--<page-tabs></page-tabs>-->
</ion-content>

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {  NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { firstPage, Tab1Page,Tab2Page} from '../index.paginas';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-second',
  templateUrl: 'second.html',
})
export class secondPage {
 Tab1Page,Tab2Page // are the component that has html and .ts
 tab1: any;
 tab2: any;

 constructor() {
  this.tab1 = Tab1Page;
  this.tab2 = Tab2Page;
 }

}
```

`firstPage` has a button to navigate directly to `secondPage`, but I want `SecondPage` to contain :

```
<ion-tabs color="primary" selectedIndex="1">
   <ion-tab tabIcon="hammer" tabTitle="Tab2" [root]="tab1">tab1</ion-tab>
   <ion-tab tabIcon="hammer" tabTitle="Tab1" [root]="tab2">tab2</ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

I want the second page to load the tabs only in this view
how can I do it?

[image]

Comment: just add it there. what is the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Add tabs to `second-page.html`.

```
<ion-tabs color="primary" selectedIndex="1">
   <ion-tab tabIcon="hammer" tabTitle="Tab2" [root]="tab1"></ion-tab>
   <ion-tab tabIcon="hammer" tabTitle="Tab1" [root]="tab1"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

Your `SecondPage.ts` class is OK. Only thing you need to do is add below code to your `html` which related with your `Tab2Page.ts`.

```
<ion-content padding>
  esta es la segunda XDDD
  <button ion-button block color="primary" navPop>back</button>
</ion-content>
```

I created a demo for you. find it [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-w8xxfh)

Comment: works great! I have a question what does goBack() do? if I associate this function with the button to return, the tabs are loaded in the first view. could instead use a function using navPop?

Comment: Just fyi; with [4.0.0-beta.18](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#400-beta18-2018-12-13) the usage of ion-tab was removed and it's not necessary to use named outlets.**Current Demo** (@ionic/angular 4.0.1) + **Explanation** can be found [here](https://github.com/servrox/demo-ionic-tab-routing/).